# Is there a way to create a calendar lookup table in Tableau Desktop or Tableau Prep

Tags: tableau-api, lookup-tables

I am trying to connect multiple datasets (csv) through the logical layer and I have look up table for most of my keys. I would like to have a common date/calendar table that can act as a lookup table connect various dates of various fact tables. In Power BI, we used to create a calendar table using M or DAX. Is there a way that I can achieve the same in Tableau? Or should I manually import a calendar table csv which can then act as a look up table.

Answer (score 0):

Create a date table csv as your date lookup table